# How to use SetClipboardViewer Function in Windows Service C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services, clipboard

I am trying to get clipboard events using SetClipboardViewer.
It works in a windows form when i override the function:

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)

that belongs to the base class System.Windows.Forms.

The problem is that i want to do it in a windows service.

Does someone knows how to get the clipboard events in a windows
service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Clipboard belongs to the session ([actually the session's winstation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx)), and there's no interactive user to do a clipboard copy in a service session. Of course you can have a clipboard listener process to relay the clipboard changes from an interactive session. You can use any protocol that works across the session, like sockets, shared memory or named pipe. [Rdpclip.exe](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/374733f1-14c6-4f57-afe9-ef5a7713adda) acts like one, though it sends data out via WTS virtual channels.

Some clipboard contents make sense when crossing the session boundary (e.g. CF_TEXT), some don't (e.g. CF_HDROP with paths from a mapped drive).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will try that as soon as posible after i tried hidden form in service.